# MySQL View Runs Longer Than Query

Tags: mysql

The below query runs in about 2 seconds but it times out when I turn it into a View.  What can I do to make it run faster as a view?

There are about 61 k rows in this table.

```
select f.fid-1 as fid,
balance - (select balance from fights prev where prev.fid < f.fid order by fid desc limit 1) as changes
from fights f
order by fid desc;
```

Comment: Unlike in other RDBMSs, views have (almost) no useful purpose in MySQL (as far as I can tell). So why not simply abandon the view.

Comment: I would like to run other queries off of this info.  I would also like to be able to permanently store the query without risk of closing it.

Comment: But all those other queries are going to be horrendously slow; MySQL views cannot (presently) use indexes. I don't understand the other point - you could store the query as a string in a table if you really wanted to!

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm not a programmer and am only "tech savy" enough to create this.

Comment: With proper DDLs, I suspect someone here could show you a better way of writing this query. To save it as a view, you'd obviously just add the words CREATE VIEW to the beginning of it. But any queries you then run against that VIEW just aren't likely to run particularly well.

Comment: @Strawberry you're a little bit off on MySQL's view capabilities.  They can and do use indexes under many circumstances... but when there's a scalar subquery in the view, that's one of the times they don't.  The workaround there is to wrap the scalar subquery inside a stored function, and reference the function in the view... but in this case, that's not going to address all the potential issues here.

Comment: @DavidRichards, does changing to `order by f.fid desc` make a difference?  The former should refer to the derived value, while the latter refers to the orifinal.  The net result is the same but the query plan could be significantly different.